# Scrolling a ListView when the mouse is hovering over the column header

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, scroll

I have the following WPF window:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="135" Width="150">
    <Grid>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListViewItem>
                <TextBlock Text="Bobby" />
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                <TextBlock Text="Chuck" />
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                <TextBlock Text="Frank" />
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                <TextBlock Text="Sarah" />
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                <TextBlock Text="Sandra" />
            </ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I can enable scrolling for the entire `ListView` using `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`, which is the default behavior. However, this does not enable scrolling when the mouse is hovering over the column header (where the text, *Name*, is displayed). How could I allow scrolling my list of names to work even when the mouse is hovering over the column header?

Comment: @dymanoid Yes, with the mouse wheel

Comment: I still stand by my assertion that modifying the UI behavior this way is a really bad idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why there is no scrolling while the mouse cursor is over the column header area is the control template of the list view.

The header area contains another `ScrollViewer` that handles the `PreviewMouseWheel` tunneling event which prevents the "main" `ScrollViewer` from doing this.

You have two ways to solve this problem.

**1st way: use code to directly scroll your "main" `ScrollViewer`.**

If you go this way, I'd recommend you to create an attached property to make this behavior reusable.

```
public static class AdvancedScrolling
{
    // Attached property boilerplate code begin...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Enabled", typeof(bool), typeof(AdvancedScrolling), new PropertyMetadata(false, EnabledChanged));

    public static void SetEnabled(UIElement element, bool value) => element.SetValue(EnabledProperty, value);

    public static bool GetEnabled(UIElement element) => (bool)element.GetValue(EnabledProperty);

    // ...Attached property boilerplate code end

    private static void EnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Affects only list views
        if (e.NewValue is true && d is ListView listview)
        {
            // We need the visual tree of the list view, so wait for loading first
            listview.Loaded += ListViewLoaded;
        }

        void ListViewLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs re)
        {
            listview.Loaded -= ListViewLoaded;

            // The default list view (grid view) control template contains
            // a Chrome Decorator with a ScrollViewer as Child.
            // We need that ScrollViewer.
            if ((VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listview, 0) as Decorator)?.Child is ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
            {
                // Hooking up the tunneling event
                listview.PreviewMouseWheel += (s, me) =>
                {
                    // Always scroll manually
                    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(
                        scrollViewer.VerticalOffset
                        - Math.Sign(me.Delta) * SystemParameters.WheelScrollLines);

                    // Set Handled to true to prevent the ScrollViewer
                    // from processing the same event one more time.
                    me.Handled = true;
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ListView local:AdvancedScrolling.Enabled="True">
```

where `local` is your namespace like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"`.

**The second way is to change the header area template**.

We just remove the scroll viewer from that area so it won't process the mouse wheel event. That will allow our "main" `ScrollViewer` to react on mouse input when the mouse cursor is over the header area.

I copied the [default control template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates?view=netframework-4.8#listview-controltemplate-examples) and removed the `ScrollViewer` from the `DockPanel` where the header area is defined.

Then you'll get something like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

                                <!-- I removed the ScrollViewer here -->

                                    <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="2,0,2,0" Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding
        Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding
        Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding 
        Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding
        Path=TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding
        Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding
        Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding
        SnapsToDevicePixels}" />

                                <ScrollContentPresenter Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local" CanContentScroll="True"
                                        CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" />
                            </DockPanel>

                            <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1"
                                    Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                    ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                    Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />

                            <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1"
                                    Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                    ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                    Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```